# Delphi XE4 with iOS addon - how to embed files

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe4

On Android / Eclipse, I can place files in e.g. assets folder. Can I do something similar in Delphi XE4 for iOS?

i.e. create a folder where data and image files can placed and automatically built into app?

I know I can have images, txt etc. in the form file, but is not what I want if I can avoid it.

...

If I include **res.zip** in **Delphi > Project > Deployment** my following code returns false in simulator:

```
FileExists(GetHomePath + PathDelim + 'res.zip')

FileExists(GetHomePath + PathDelim + 'Documents' + PathDelim + 'res.zip')
```

For reference, **RemoteDir** in deployment was set to ./

Comment: Not sure why it got downvoted, as I think it is a valid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this (this is from code where I have a TClientDataSet that I use on iOS.

```
uses System.SysUtils;

procedure TdtmdlNestoria.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  cdsSearches.FileName := GetHomePath + PathDelim + 'Documents' + PathDelim + 'Searchs.xml';
end;
```

If you are loading a file that you are deploying to the device you will also need to make sure that the project source has System.StartUpCopy as the first item in the uses. (Right click on the project and choose View Source) 
e.g.

```
program Project6;

uses
  System.StartUpCopy,
  FMX.Forms,
  Unit5 in 'Unit5.pas' {Form5};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm5, Form5);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found that you can use the "Project > Deployment" secttion and then choose to store all files in remote folder "StartUp\Documents\".

Comment: Talking about deployment. I have about 100 small/medium sized files. Could I zip this into one and deployt it through above. Then at runtime at first run uncompress files into a private folder? (Or should I simply add all 100 files into "Project > Deployment")

Comment: I marked as valid answer. I still have a little problem with the "Project / Deployment", but I am on right track now. (I also found Apple's app iOS file system description page documentation)