# how to access to file stored in \StartUp\Documents\?

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

In iOS, how can I access files deployed in "\StartUp\Documents\"? it's look like it's the path where resources get deployed, but I don't know how to find the path from the running app. i try:

```
TPath.Combine(TPath.GetHomePath, 'StartUp/Documents/mypict.png')
```

without any success :(

Comment: Make sure the `System.StartupCopy` unit is at the top of the `uses` clause in your main project file. Then remove `StartUp` from the path you access the file with: `TPath.Combine(TPath.GetHomePath, 'Documents/mypict.png')` See [Delphi XE4 with iOS addon - how to embed files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17193344/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau hmm, so now i have another question: what the purpose of the System.StartUpCopy.pas? I open a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61942454/what-the-purpose-of-the-system-startupcopy-pas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files you deploy to StartUp/Documents in your Deployment settings get copied into your apps sandbox documents folder by System.StartupCopy.pas when the app first runs. To access those files you can use the following code:

`TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'mypict.png')`